# Is it possible to reuse a task in two different spots in a Luigi pipeline?

Tags: python, luigi

I am developing a Luigi pipeline and am running into a major problem. There doesn't seem to be any way to reuse tasks in the same pipeline.
To illustrate what I am after, consider the following workflow:

`Collect_Data → Clean_data → Task_on_data_A → Task_on_data_B
                     ↳ Sample_data → Task_on_data_A → Task_on_data_B`

I perform the same operations on `Clean_data` and `Sample_data`. I want to do something like this in Luigi while following DRY principles. Right now it seems like I have to literally copy and paste my code for tasks A and B to do this.

Airflow has [a way to deal with situations like this.](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#subdags) Does Luigi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should draw the arrows as dependency arrows going the other way. It helps to think about it this way since the execution path is determined by the requires methods. In your scenario, it is very simple because you just have a TaskA that has a conditional dependency.

You just need to add one more task at the start that depends on two TaskBs and an indicator of whether the taskb is to be run on the sample

Pseudocode:

```
ParentTask
  def requires():
     return [TaskB(sample_type=True), 
             TaskB(sample_type=False)]

TaskB
  def requires():
    return TaskA(sample_type)

TaskA
  def requires():
    if sample_type:
      return SampleTask()
    else:
      return CleanTask()

SampleTask
  def requires():
    return CleanTask()

CleanTask
  def requires()
    return CollectData()
```

Comment: No question this works, but doesn't it make code reuse complicated?  I need to hard code the source of data in my task.  So if someone comes later and makes a different sample_data and wants to use TaskA-TaskB, they've got to edit the source (or recreate) TaskA?  Feels very anti-duck typing.  It just feels odd for something in python

Comment: Andrew- I would not recommend hard-coding the source of data in the task. It would be better to parameterize it in ParentTask and pass it down the stack. It is a different way of thinking though, as you have to always start with what you want as the result, and think about how that affects the steps you need to get there, instead of starting by thinking about the first step.